# Count distinct does not work in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I need to count distinct date in one column but I do not want to group by that.

Datasource table:

```
ID   zip5    date       volume  
11   11111   01/03/16   5  
12   11111   01/03/16   6
13   11111   01/04/16   7
```

My code:

```
Select zip5, count(ID), count(distinct (date)), sum(volume), 
from table
group by zip5
```

Desired output:

```
zip5   count(ID)  count(distinct (date))  sum(volume)
11111          2                       1           11
11111          1                       1            7
```

However, what I got is:

```
zip5   count(ID)  count(distinct (date))  sum(volume)
11111          3                       3           18
```

Comment: You've tagged this for three competing database products. Are you using all three?

Comment: If you group by zip5, you can't expect something different, the expected result (with the input you're giving) is the line 11111 3 3 18.

Comment: You've also tagged it for PL/SQL Developer, but have SQL Developer in the title. Not that the client matters here, but it would help if you were clear about which client and database you were actually using.

Comment: To expand on @Paolof76's comment, if you include the `date` column in the `GROUP BY` you may get the result you are expecting.

Comment: To get the output you want u will need to group by zip,date

Comment: In Oracle by zip, "DATE" (due to reserved words).

Comment: You do not want to group by it? But that will give you the answer you need!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the problem you are facing is that your `date` column has a time component -- and, alas, it is not shown when you select from the table.

You can truncate the date to remove the time component.  So try this:

```
Select zip5, count(ID), count(distinct trunc(date)), sum(volume), 
from table
group by zip5;
```

Comment: Linoff. Thank you very much!. It works. Why the date data format will matter? You mean like minute/second which not show in data?

Comment: @MichaelLi  . . . Correct.  Oracle does not, by default, show the time component of a `date` column.

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired output simple add the "DATE" column in the GROUP BY expression.

```
Select zip5, count(ID), count(distinct ("DATE")), sum(volume)
from "TABLE"
group by zip5,"DATE"
order by 1,2;

      ZIP5  COUNT(ID) COUNT(DISTINCT("DATE")) SUM(VOLUME)
---------- ---------- ----------------------- -----------
     11111          1                       1           7 
     11111          2                       1          11
```

You may group by (i.e. select in disctinct rows) even columns that are not in the select list.